# Java Custom Server, Works mostly but randomly fails

Tags: java, http, server

So I've been trying to learn more about how web sites and http requests and the like, so a project I've been working on is setting up my own server in pure java. For the most part it's been successful, I've learned a ton and it works pretty well, but it seems like after it has been idle for awhile, it is no longer listening to requests. Here's the applicable code, the portion that handles the requests is relatively straightforward. I've also gotten rid of println statements I use for logging:

```
public class Server{
public static void main(String args[]){
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    ServerSocket server = null;
    try{
        server = new ServerSocket(5555);
    }//end of try
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error setting up listener");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }//end of catch
    while(true){
        try{
            clientSocket = server.accept();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            new HandleRequest(reader.readLine(),clientSocket).start();
        }//end of try
        catch(Exception e){
            //send 500 error header and error message
        }//end of catch
    }//end of while
  }//end of main
}//end of Server class
```

HandleRequest is a class that extends Thread and it figures out what to send back to the client and writes it back to the socket that is sent to it. But the issue is that in some cases when attempting to connect, the server.accept() portion does not even fire (although this isn't always the case, one night I started the server and in the morning it still worked, but this is not usually the case). Also occasionally if I attempt to connect a second time, this will cause the server to process both requests, which is a bit odd to me. Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

edit: I'm also aware that this is terrible practice only reading the first line of the request and that it only works with GET requests. As mentioned it's a learning project for me, not meant to be used for anything important, although that may be something I try to implement next.

Answer (score 1):

The client-handling thread should do the `readLine()` itself. At present if you have a misbehaving client it will block the accepting thread.

Comment: oh that actually makes a ton of sense, I'll try that. Any idea what would cause a client to "misbehave"?

Comment: Bugs, or malicious actors. For example, connecting but not sending anything. Common DOS attack.